# 'go mod init example.com/m' to initialize a v0 or v1 module

Tags: go, go-gorm, go-gin

I am learning at https://youtu.be/ma7rUS_vW9M?t=73

Video

[image]

My environment

[image]

```
D:\temp2023_03_01\go\src>go version
go version go1.20.1 windows/amd64
```

My actions

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1265]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

D:\temp2023_03_01\go\src\github.com\robbyklein\go-jwt>go mod init
go: cannot determine module path for source directory D:\temp2023_03_01\go\src\github.com\robbyklein\go-jwt (outside GOPATH, module path must be specified)

Example usage:
        'go mod init example.com/m' to initialize a v0 or v1 module
        'go mod init example.com/m/v2' to initialize a v2 module

Run 'go help mod init' for more information.

D:\temp2023_03_01\go\src\github.com\robbyklein\go-jwt>
```

[image]

Why my result is different with video? What I do for archive result like the video?

Comment: Please do not post images of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
D:\temp2023_03_01\go\src>go mod init github.com/robbyklein/go-jwt
go: creating new go.mod: module github.com/robbyklein/go-jwt
```

Answer (score 2):

https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Initialize_new_module_in_current_directory

> Init accepts one optional argument, the module path for the new module. If the module path argument is omitted, init will attempt to infer the module path using import comments in .go files, vendoring tool configuration files (like Gopkg.lock), and the current directory (if in GOPATH).

Your GOPATH is set to `D:\vygopath` but the project for which you are running `go mod init` is located in `D:\temp2023_03_01\go\src`. If you want `go mod init` to work without module-path then you should move the project over to `D:\vygopath\src` instead. After that the `go mod init` command should work, the tool should be able to infer the module-path.

[image]

Comment: It did not work as you said https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1328316/222188235-c9bbeb6d-6eb9-470e-b72f-7a5aeba294a5.png . `D:\vygopath\src\github.com\robbyklein\go-jwt>go mod init`

Comment: I wouldn't suggest moving a project _into_ GOPATH, since that is deprecated and the inferred module path was only to help upgrade legacy projects (and judging by the reply, it may not even work any longer)

Comment: @JimB The fact that it didn't work for OP only suggests that OP did something wrong, I think. For me, it works as documented in the linked docs: https://imgur.com/a/7v1sQX6

Comment: looks like you're right it does seem to work. I only meant that _"you should move the project over to ..."_ sounds like endorsing moving the project back into `GOPATH` rather than using the correct invocation of `go mod init module.name` (even though you were technically answering the question ;))

Comment: @RaphaëlColantonio make sure `$GOPATH` is set in the `cmd.exe` session in which you are running `go mod init`. And make sure to use _that_ `$GOPATH` (in case it's different from `D:\vygopath`) as the root of your project if you want `go mod init` to work. But, as JimB already pointed out, relying on GOPATH is out of date, specifying the module-path explicitly like you did in your answer is the recommended approach these days.